# A closed path in a sphere separates it in two connected components. Hints to prove?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact connected $1$-manifold ($C^{\infty}$) contained in the unit sphere $S^{2}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Show that $S^{2}-M$ has two connected components, with $M$ as a common boundary.

I suppose I could mimic the Jordan-Brouwer theorem on orientable connected surfaces, but I don't know how to fit this exactly in there. I also don't know If this could be done maybe using the Jordan-Brouwer theorem somehow.

Any hints on how to start this will be welcome! Thanks.

Comment: It is the Jordan curve theorem. Take a point outside $M$ (why is there such?) and remove that from $S^2$ and you have $M$ inside  a homeomorph of $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Wikipedia statement of the Jordan curve theorem, I'd start this way:  There must be some point of $S^2$ which is not in $M$.  Removing that turns $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Applying the Jordan curve theorem gives the conclusion.  I'm sure there are details I've omitted, especially showing that a compact, connected 1-manifold is homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: Oh right, this theorem can be applied for a homeomorphic one aswell. Thanks!